# Why do i have to reference in this situation?

Tags: c++

```
int main(){

while(true){

    char input = getchar();
    int x, y;
    POINT xypos;

    if (input == 'S' || input == 's'){

        std::cout <<"enter new position" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> x >> y;
        SetCursorPos(x, y);

    } else if (input == 'g' || input == 'G'){

        GetCursorPos(&xypos);
        std::cout << "X: " << xypos.x << "Y " << xypos.y << std::endl;
    }
}


    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain why with `GetCursorPos`, it has to reference the xypos object in the parameters? Why is it not possible to directly utilize it? Thanks

Comment: What are `SetCursorPos()` and `GetCursorPos()`?

Comment: It looks like `GetCursorPos` takes a `POINT*`, not a reference.

Comment: @scohe001 I assume their talking about the win32 function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean why `GetCursorPos`(from the WinAPI) doesn't just return the position instead of taking a pointer and filling that right?

That's how the WinAPI works, almost all functions return `BOOL` to indicate success or failure and take information they populate by pointer.

Comment: Do you return `BOOL`? Or do you like to populate with your pointer?

Comment: @Bathsheba I used to return `BOOL` but then I switched to taking the g-`string` by pointer and just not returning it.